# Login to Localhost on for JBoss Wildfly 10

Tags: java, jboss

I am just started to learn Java EE on Jboss Wildfly based on a tutorial.
When setting up the environment on Windows10, I am facing that I was able to start the server by typing standalone in the command prompt, but I cannot logon to localhost:8080 as instructed as I am prompted to provide a user name and password to do so. I tried my windows password but it doesn't work. 
I would appreciate some help to be able to start. Which value to provide or how to disable this security-feature? 
Thank you

Comment: See _Managing your WildFly 10_  on [this page](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Getting+Started+Guide) for instructions on how to add a user

Comment: Yes, I found this page as well and made the steps described in the authentication part, but didn't help

Comment: If you followed those steps, you should have made a new user. You should be able to use the new user/password to log in to the admin console _http://localhost:9990/console_

Comment: Indeed, I can, but I thought that I need to logon to localhost:8080, too, and it is still not possible. Do I need it at all?

Comment: If you deploy an application to WildFly, it will be available at _localhost:8080/YourApplicationName_. So if you haven't deployed any applications yet, you have nothing to do with localhost:8080

Comment: thanks a lot for your help